# Keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" inside of $scope.$watch function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get a value from a container that, on a change in its value, triggers a $scope.$watch that starts another function. I can only get the error above, even though I can confirm that it is retrieving the correct value. 
My suspicion is that `$watch` is loading before the color variable has a chance to initialize.

My AngularJS Script:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('careApp.tMain', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/tMain', {
    templateUrl: './templates/tMain.html',
    controller: 'tMainCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('tMainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.dimmer = 100;
  $scope.color = '#c24747';

  $scope.$watch('color', function(){
    console.log('Color has changed to ' + $scope.color);
    hexToRGB($scope.color);
  })
});
```

The `$watch` function watches over the following chunk of HTML code:

```
        <div>
           <!-- $watch looks for changes here-->
           <ng-farbtastic ng-model="color"></ng-farbtastic>

            <md-input-container class="hide">
                <label>Color</label>
                <!-- Curly brace 'color' variable from farbtastic.js code -->
                <input type="text" value="{{color}}">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
```

***What do I need to do to correct this error?***

Comment: You're using `ng-model` _and_ have a `value` attribute- you don't need `value`. Also why is the input box `readonly`? This might be where the problems are coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the `readonly` and `value` attribute from your html.

```
<md-input-container class="hide">
   <label>Color</label>
   <input type="text" ng-model='color'>
</md-input-container>
```

Now in your controller, the value of the `$scope.color` should have been updated automatically when there is a change in the ng-model from your page.

In case if you want to use the $watch functionality then, here it is.

```
$scope.$watch(function()
    {
       return $scope.color
    },
    function(newVal,oldVal){
       if (oldVal!==newVal){
          console.log('Color has changed to ' + newVal);
          hexToRGB(newVal);
       }
  });
```

Comment: Perfect! I had a lot of redundant things that weren't going to the same place. I also uncovered a small bug thanks to changing the $watch functionality. Thanks for your help!